# Calling refresh on ListView after changing inner adapter content

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I am populating my ListView like this:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity { ... 

    public void populateDemoTasksList() 
    {

      lvTasksList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tasksListView);
      tasks_list = databaseHandler.getAllTasks();
      TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(this, tasks_list);
      lvTasksList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Now i got x tasks shown on my ListeView.

Now i am updateing my Task Adapter class:

```
public class TaskAdapter implements ListAdapter, View.OnClickListener {

Context context;
List<Task> tasks;
final DatabaseHandler db_handler;     ... 
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{ 
        Button task_menu_bt = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.EraseTaskButton);
        task_menu_bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                db_handler.deleteTaskByUUID(data.getUuid());
                changeDataSource(db_handler.getAllTasks());

            //  HomeActivity.deleteTaskAndRefresh(data.getUuid());

            }
        });
```

When  a user click on one of the ListView erase button i want to erase the row from the view.

The row is indeed erased from the table (which populate the view), BUT my problem is that the presented row is not deleted on the spot, but only when the user open other activity and get back to the original activity.

My question is how to call populateDemoTasksList(which is a part of HomeActivity that extends activity) after the onClick event of my TaskAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just pass an instance of your HomeActivity in constructor of your `TaskAdapter` and call the method `populateDemoTasksList()` using that instance of HomeActivity and then just refresh the Adapter of your ListView.

You are already passing context to your Adapter so just cast it with your HomeActivity to get instance of HomeActivity and use it!

```
HomeActivity activity = (HomeActivity) context;
```

Answer (score 1):

While answer provided by Lalit Poptani might be considered as a way to go (and indeed - this is the easiest solution), but in real apps it will just bring a dose of confusion into code, because it hides the general idea - your `Activity` should react on **database** update. It means that update notification should be issued as close as possible to actual database update (which is definately not an `Adapter`).

In your case you have `DatabaseHandler` which is responsible for database modification, so it should notify `Activity` about such updates. How? Well, you have plenty of options, like:

- Directly add\remove listeners from `DatabaseHandler`
- Register `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` and send broadcasts from `DatabaseHandler`
- Use `ContentProvider` + `CursorLoader`, which have built-in mechanism for such updates

Exact solution depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Once you delete from the database, delete the same from data source of list by calling and refresh the list as follows,

```
    remove(getItem(position));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```